# how do I select to collations for sql server database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, collation, culture

I am working with a number of sql server 2012 databases that contain data from different languages. I have been reading up on such and have found getting the collations for the sql server databases correct is something that needs careful consideration. I am not familliar with such and could really do with some assistance. Let me outline, what languages are in which database:

- Database 1 - Russian data
- Database 2 - Polish and English data
- Database 3 - Kyrgyz and Russian data

How do I go about deciding on the collations are for each database? Is there a guide I can follow or any tips on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here for a guide (not yet a version for SQL 2012, but it should be the same):

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174903(v=sql.80).aspx

Also, regardless of collation I'd recommend always using `NVARCHAR` / `NCHAR` columns over `VARCHAR` / `CHAR`.  (I would say `NTEXT` too, but that's deprecated anyway in 2008 and upwards).

```
Database 1 - Russian data - `Cyrillic_General_CI_AS`
Database 2 - Polish and English data - `SQL_Polish_Cp1250_CI_AS_KI_WI`
Database 3 - Kyrgyz and Russian data - `Cyrillic_General_CI_AS`
```

NB: I'm not 100% on Polish and English where things like sorting data alphabetically are concerned; the others I'm pretty confident on though.

Comment: John, many thanks - very helpful. Can I ask, how did you come up with these collations? have read both links and it did not jump out to me where this information may be.

Comment: Cyrillic I knew, Polish I did a search for that word on the first link.  Looking now for something a bit more useful . . . In the meantime I found this which shows what's included in the collation / the sort order: http://www.collation-charts.org/mssql/mssql.0415.1250.Polish_CS_AI.html

Comment: I can't find anything better than the above MSDN link I'm afraid - surprising there don't seem to be any tables/tools to list languages against collations out there.  Sorry~